# Getting error while running me flutter project

Tags: flutter, dart

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':agora_rtc_engine:generateDebugRFile'.

> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':agora_rtc_engine:debugCompileClasspath'.
> Failed to transform full-sdk-4.2.1.aar (io.agora.rtc:full-sdk:4.2.1) to match attributes {artifactType=android-symbol-with-package-name, org.gradle.category=library, org.gradle.libraryelements=jar, org.gradle.status=release, org.gradle.usage=java-api}.
> > Execution failed for ExtractAarTransform: C:\Users\sahir.gradle\caches\transforms-3\d7b9b9781f6f39ebf93efcf97e80e768\transformed\jetified-full-sdk-4.2.1.aar.
> > There is not enough space on the disk

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Unhandled exception:
FileSystemException: writeFrom failed, path = 'C:\Users\sahir\AppData\Local\Temp\flutter_tools.c09ef4ad\flutter_tool.a166bfa9\app.dill' (OS Error: There is not enough space on the disk.

, errno = 112)
#0      _checkForErrorResponse (dart:io/common.dart:55)
#1      _RandomAccessFile.writeFrom. (dart:io/file_impl.dart:885)

#2      _FileStreamConsumer.addStream... (dart:io/file_impl.dart:218)

the Dart compiler exited unexpectedly.
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Resolve this error please

Comment: Add the part of the code that is giving the error for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I think the log is clear. It says **There is not enough space on the disk**.  So delete some stuff to get more space and retry; and if you get errors delete **caches** directory from *C:\Users\sahir.gradle\caches* (and try again).